# How should I start with a large amount of data with limited computation?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, amazon-redshift

I have an assignment in which there are various .csv files containing over 5-8GB of data.
My local computer has only 16GB RAM, and I have a task where I have to create an SQL query out of the files and then create a ML python algorithm, then create a Tableau dashboard out of it.

I have always used data to do all 3 of these tasks separately, on a database that has already been given, but I've never had to upload the data myself and create a database myself, and I am absolutely stuck. Also, I haven't used such large amount of data before.

Where should I start? How can I create a database? Any help...?

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is a very vague question. Try to be more specific and describe the particular issue you're facing.

Comment: I have multiple .csv files that are just huge amounts of data. I want to create a database in which I can connect and create a query/python etc. May you have any reccommendations? I have no idea where to start.....

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html - loads data from CSV to MySQL table directly. Fast. Low memory consumption, even when CSV is large.

Comment: *How can I create a database?* You should read about databases.. well, at least something.

Comment: You can also use postgresql as the container database to load the large amount of data.  Once you have the database, you can make full use of the query functionality and will consume not much memory.